# proofs that limit exists

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, logarithms

Calculate the following limits (including proofs that they exist):
$$(a) \lim _{x \rightarrow 0+} x^x$$
$$(b) \lim _{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos ^2 x}{\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2}$$
$$(c) \lim _{x \rightarrow \pi} \frac{\sin m x}{\sin x}$$
$$(d) \lim _{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}}(\tan x)^{\tan 2 x}$$

These are the exercises from the chapter ''Logarithms and Exponentials'' It is not hard to calculate the limits, but the requirement <<(including proofs that they exist)>> seems troublesome for me. Should I do it with $\varepsilon$ , $\delta$ definition of the limit ( which is irritating) or there is simpler way??

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: I'm not sure what $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are supposed to be for part (e) (Continuous? Differentiable?), but the others, at least, look like classic l'Hopital's rule questions. Using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ would be extraordinarily difficult. L'Hoptial's rule actually does prove a limit exists: if $\lim f'(x)/g'(x)$ exists, then l'Hopital's rule proves that $\lim f(x)/g(x)$ exists as well, and is equal to the same limit (though beware: the converse is not true; l'Hopital's rule can never prove a limit does not exist).

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks a lot it was very helpful.

Comment: No problem! Hope it goes well.

Comment: $\epsilon-\delta$ proof are not the only way. Take into account that many properties of limits give the existence of a limit, once you know the existence (and possibly some conditions on the values) of some other limits. For example, if you know that the limits $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=M$ exist, and $L$ and $M$ are not one $0$ and the other $\pm\infty$, then the limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)$ exists and it is $LM$. Perhaps you know already that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ exists and it is $1$. You can deduce the existence (and the value) of (c) from this one.

Comment: again thanks everyone. @TheoBendit I think you have to public your comment as an answer/

Comment: Many other theorems (than L'Hopital) can be used to compute these limits, but all of them simultaneously prove their existence. The same happens with similar exercises about improper integrals. You are right to be troubled by the (falsely additional) requirement <<(including proofs that they exist)>>.

Comment: @AnneBauval hmm it is interesting that you are saying this is falsely additional requirement and computing limits simultaneously prove their existence, if I understood rightly

Comment: *These are the exercises from the chapter ''Logarithms and Exponentials''* --- There are thousands of books over a period of some 200 years with such a chapter, so I think you need to be a bit more specific than this for the citation!

Comment: @emilagazade, you cannot compute something that you do not know exists. If your argument to compute something does not in fact also prove that what ypou are computing actually exists, then your argument is simply wrong.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez that is why I was confused. So asked this question. However these are not difficult limits. But authors require "include also proofs that they are exists" confused me

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe try to bound from above these functions with another function that it's limit at $x_0$ exists. For example, for the first case, note that: $x^x=e^{xln(x)}$ for $x>0$ and also note that $e^x$ is strictly increasing and $lnx\leq x-1$ for all $x>0$. Thus, $x^x\leq e^{x^2-x}$ and since the limit of $e^{x^2-x}$ as $x\to 0^{+}$ exists( it is equal to 1), we conclude that the limit of $x^x$ as $x\to 0^{+}$ exists.